# self-invoking functions

Tags: javascript, function

when I code:

```
var a =
function()
{
    alert("44")
    return function(){alert(33)}
}()();
```

is this expression evaluated in the following order?

1. define the function;
2. pass its reference pointer to a
3. a() is invoked
4. return in a a new function pointer
5. a() is invoked again

and if so why do I have a syntax error if I do:

```
function()
{
    alert("44")
    return function(){alert(33)}
}();
```

the interpreter wants a left operand first...

but this syntax works:

```
(
  function()
  {
    alert("44")
    return function(){alert(33)}
  };

)()
```

the outer parenthesis what does meaning???

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the syntax of the language. If you want to in-place execute an anonymous function, you must enclose it in parens.

JS has these edge cases where the syntax is weirder than you expect. Take for example, evaling a string that has a JSON doesn't work unless it's wrapped with parens.

```
// Wrong
eval("{ ... }");
// Right
eval("({ ... })");
```

It's the syntax of the language.

That said, I think (and this is strictly IMHO), the steps you've outlined are not accurate.

1. Function is defined and invoked. alert("44"); happens as a result.
2. The function returns another function which is also invoked. alert("33"); happens.
3. The innermost function doesn't return anything, so a is effectively undefined. typeof a returns "undefined".

Answer (score 3):

1. **`function() { alert("44") return function(){alert(33)} }`**
   *you define the function*
2. `function() { alert("44") return function(){alert(33)} }`**`()`** 
   *you call that function returning anonymous function* `function(){alert(33)}`
3. `function() { alert("44") return function(){alert(33)} }()`**`()`**
   *you call returned function, so it's actually equivalent to* `function(){alert(33)}()`

So the whole execution is equivalent to:

```
alert("44"); alert(33);
```

Answer (score 0):

i just learning self-invoking functions,too.
and i think the code should be
3. `(function() { alert("44"); return function(){alert(33);} })()()`